# Rails: skipping password validation for guest user only with has_secure_password

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an application where I have 2 types of users, a **Normal User** and a **Guest User**. I'm using **has_secure_password** for password functionality.

What I need is to skip the validation for password (length and that confirmation matches password) if the user is guest, but validate if the user isn't. I now have the following code, where has_secure_password(validation: false) is added to allow guest functionality

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }, unless: :guest?

  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true if :guest?
  # validates :password_confirmation=, presence: true, allow_nil: true if :guest?

  has_secure_password(validations: false)
```

The problem with this, is that there is no validation that the password and password_confirmation match when a normal user is created.

I tried overcoming this by creating custom validation for password_confirmation (the commented line), but I felt this is not the rails way of doing this.

What I'm trying to find out is, how can I skip has_secure_password only in the case of the guest users? If this is not possible, how can I validate for password_confirmation manually?